# Is $y=mx+b$ linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

Consider $f(x) = mx+b$. Let $b\ne 0$

1. If $f$ is linear, $f(0)$ should yield $0$
2. $f(0) = m(0)+b = b$
3. Therefore $f(x)=mx+b$ is nonlinear.

**Question**:

Why is $y=mx+b$ called a "[linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation)"?

---

**Remark:**

Consider $f(x,y) = y + -mx = b$

\begin{align}
\alpha f(x,y) &= \alpha b \\
f(\alpha x,\alpha y) &= \alpha y +-\alpha mx = \alpha (y +-mx) =\alpha b
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f(x+\beta,y+\beta) &= y + \beta+ - m (x +\beta) \\&= (y+-mx)+(\beta +-m\beta)\\
&= f(x,y)+ f(\beta,\beta) 
\end{align}

Therefore, $f(x,y) = y +-mx$ and $f(x,y) =b$ are linear.

**Question:**

Why is this not a contradiction?

Comment: Maybe because the word "affine" is too scary for middle schoolers?

Comment: Haha, not the middle schoolers I grew up with, but point taken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're probably stuck with this peculiar inconsistency of terminology on account of the prevalence of the term *linear* to refer to relationships like (the one between $x, y$ in) $y = m x + b$ in secondary education. I would anyway still call this a *linear equation*: We can rewrite it as
$$\pmatrix{-m & 1}\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{b},$$ which is a *linear system* in standard matrix form that happens to correspond to a single equation in $2$ variables.

In isolation, *linear* is a fine term for such relationships: One can guess its etymology by inspection---Latin *linea*, meaning line---and surely it refers to the shape of the graph of such an equation.

On the other hand, like the question observes, this conflicts with the notion of linearity of a map in linear algebra, in the sense that $T(x) := m x + b$ is a linear transformation iff $T(0) = b = 0$. In that setting, we instead call such transformations *affine*: More precisely, we say that a transformation $S : \Bbb V \to \Bbb W$ between vector spaces is *affine* iff there is a linear transformation $T: \Bbb V \to \Bbb W$ and an element ${\bf w} \in \Bbb W$ such that $S({\bf v}) = T({\bf v}) + {\bf w}$ for all ${\bf v} \in \Bbb V$. Indeed, ${\bf w} = T({\bf 0}) + {\bf w} = S({\bf 0})$ and $T({\bf v}) = S({\bf v}) - {\bf w}$, so such a decomposition is unique.

**Remark** We can still regard affine transformations as linear ones using a standard "embedding" trick: The above definition implies that the space of affine transformations $\Bbb V \to \Bbb W$ is itself a vector space, isomorphic to $(\Bbb W \otimes \Bbb V^*) \oplus \Bbb W$. Now, we can encode the general affine transformation $S({\bf v}) = T({\bf v}) + {\bf w}$ as the linear transformation $\Bbb F \oplus \Bbb V \to \Bbb F \oplus \Bbb W$ (here, $\Bbb F$ is the field underlying $\Bbb V$ and $\Bbb W$) with block matrix representation
$$[S] = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ {\bf w} & T},$$
which has the following feature: If we identify ${\bf x} \in \Bbb V$ with $[{\bf x}] := \pmatrix{1 \\ {\bf x}} \in \Bbb F \oplus \Bbb V$ and likewise ${\bf y} \in \Bbb W$ with $[{\bf y}] = \pmatrix{1 \\ {\bf y}} \in \Bbb F \oplus \Bbb W$, then we have
$$[S] [{\bf x}] = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ {\bf w} & T} \pmatrix{1 \\ {\bf x}} = \pmatrix{1 \\ T({\bf x}) + {\bf w}} = \pmatrix{1 \\ S({\bf x})} = [S({\bf x})].$$ In short, we have exploited the fact that the restriction of a linear transformation to any affine subspace is an affine transformation and, for a given affine transformation, cooked up a linear transformation of which it is a restriction.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The embedding you mention is used in computer graphics as [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) concept, which allows to handle the usual gang of transformations as matrices.

Comment: @mvw That's a very useful comment, I think, and it's worth noting that such matrices are accordingly sometimes called *affine matrices*. If one restricts to invertible transformations from a vector space $\Bbb V$ to itself, one gets a group $GL(\Bbb V) \ltimes \Bbb V$ called the *affine group*.

Answer (score 9):

The word "linear" is used in mathematics in many different ways. A "linear equation" is not necessary the same thing as a "linear function" or a "linear functional" or a "linear map" or etc.

Comment: Indeed, if a "linear equation" were linear in the form the OP expects, it would always have a trivial solution.

Comment: To distinguish between them $ (b \ne 0, b=0) $  hope they may be referred to as linear relation and proportionate relation respy.

Answer (score 5):

Colloquially, equations of the form $y=mx+b$ are called *linear*, because they geometrically represent straight **lines** in the Cartesian plane.

Rigorously (especially in advanced mathematical fields like functional analysis), such functions are generally called *affine*, and the adjective *linear* is reserved for the case $b=0$.

Apparently, a slight contradiction emerges from the usage of these terms. Deal with it.

---

As for the remark, the function $f(x,y)=y-mx$ is linear, indeed (in the rigorous sense of the word), as a function of the $\underline{\text{two}}$ variables $(x,y)$. However, what the expression $$f(x,y)=y-mx=b$$ defines is *not* a function; it is a *restriction* imposing that the linear function $f(x,y)=y-mx$ must take the value $b$. If you rearrange this restriction, you get $y=mx+b$, which gives $y$ as a function $x$. This resulting new function of $\underline{\text{one}}$ variable, $g(x)=mx+b$, is *not* linear anymore (unless $b=0$), but affine.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a contradiction because $f(x) $ and $f(x,y)$ are not the same thing.

Had you defined $f(x,y)=y-mx-b=0 $ you would have deduced that $f(x,y)$ was non-linear .

It's all a matter of wether or not you include the constant $b$ in your definition of $f$

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So I was just sloppy then unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

There are many definitions for "linear", one in colloquial maths, and one in formal maths.

In colloquial maths a linear function is a function in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

In a formal sense, a lineal function is a function $f$ defined from a vector space $V$ to another, $W$ (Over a field $F$), such that:
$$f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v),u,v\in V$$
And
$$f(\alpha u)=\alpha f(u),\alpha\in F$$

Clearly the colloquial definition does not coincide with this. Formally, the colloquial linear function would be called an Affine mapping, function, transformation, etc.

About the second part, if you consider it as a function of 2 variables, it **may** become linear. But think that you'd be talking about different things, the first as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the second as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think if the asker knew what a vector space is they would not be asking this question to begin with. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Not necessarily, many students (Me included) learn about vector spaces before learning about linear mappings in a formal sense. And he seems to be enough open-minded to talk about bivariate functions...

Now that I think so, it was after seeing vector spaces and when learnign linear mappings that I thought something similar, about how the "Calculus" linear functions wouldn´t be the same as the linear algebra ones.

Comment: I think the point is that $f(x) = mx + b$ is not a linear-algebra function. It's a "calculus" linear function. There's nothing "colloquial" about calling it linear; it's just in a different domain of math.

Comment: Well, i wouldn't want to call it linear even in calculus, because in more advanced calculus we start working with linear transformations and using linear in both cases would be a little ambiguous (It can be worked like that)...

Answer (score 1):

You write:

1. If $f$ is linear, $f(0)$ should yield $0$

This is misleading, because it describes $f$ incompletely.
To be more precise, what you could write is:

$1'$. If $f$ is a linear *transformation*, then $f(\mathbf 0) = \mathbf 0.$

That is a direct consequence of the definition of a linear transformation $f$,
which requires (in part) that $f(\alpha \mathbf v) = \alpha f(\mathbf v)$
for every scalar $\alpha$ and every vector $\mathbf v.$
Note that in statement $1'$, the symbol $\mathbf 0$ is the zero *vector*,
not a scalar.

On the other hand, when we write

$$ f(x) = mx + b, $$

then $f$ is not a linear transformation.
Rather, it is a scalar-valued function.

A *linear function* generally refers to such a scalar-valued function.
In other words:

- linear function: $f(0) = b$, where $b$ is a scalar, not necessarily zero.
- linear transformation: $f(\mathbf 0) = \mathbf 0$, where $\mathbf 0$ is a vector.

There is some (slight) potential for confusion because the word "linear" modifies "function" and "transformation" in different ways, but there is
no actual contradiction.

**Aside:** As noted in some other answers, it is possible to
model a linear function using a linear transformation on a suitably
defined vector space, and it is sometimes useful to do so;
this is a standard computer graphics technique.
There is still a lot of mathematics (not just at the middle school level!)
in which this kind of modeling is not done, however,
and "linear" refers to first-degree polynomials just as
"quadratic" refers to second-degree polynomials.

Comment: I thought $\Bbb{R}$ was a vector space and so $f(0)=0$ should be fine because I was considering the one dimensional case. Is this an inconsistent or problematic interpretation of what $f$ is?

Comment: You _can_ interpret $\mathbb R$ as a vector space. But people do sometimes take $\mathbb R$ to be a field of scalars instead. (In fact I suspect they do that rather more often than interpreting it as a vector space.)

Comment: Hmm. I didn't realize one was preferred or I might have made this distinction. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Thinking about this further, it occurs to me that the difference between these two uses of the word "linear" may be a historical accident. Perhaps if linear algebra had developed before the "ordinary" algebra originally used in calculus, we might have one word that always implied $f(0)=0$ and another word that describes $f(x) = mx+b.$ Presumably, if "linear" had consistently been used only for objects of the first kind then we would also have a different name for what we now call linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

Here in school $y = m x + b$ is called a linear function, and the special case $b=0$ a [proportional function](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionalit%C3%A4t#Aktuelle_Definition).

The reason for naming it linear function is probably its graph, which is a straight line.

The distinction into linear and affine equations comes later, when linear algebra and analytic geometry are covered.

So we have different meanings here between calculus and algebra.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that $y=mx+b$ is a linear equation because it can be expressed as the matrix equation:$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-m&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
b
\end{bmatrix}
$$This works because the coefficients $1$ and $-m$, as well as the variable $b$, are constant with respect to $x$ and $y$.

I would not say $f(x)=mx+b$ is a linear transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship of variables $x$ and $y$ in the equation $y=mx+b$ is linear hence called as linear equation.Viewing it as map $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ define $f(x)=(x,mx+b)$ for which $f(0)=(0,b)=(0,0)$ iff $b=0$ is true. Hence $f$ is not a linear map unless $b=0$.